# Pegar conteúdo de div com classes iguais

Tags: jquery

Como eu faço pra pegar o conteúdo que está dentro de `p`? Eu consegui, mas tá listando todos os conteúdos e não apenas o que é clicado.

E outra duvida, como faço pra chamar uma função no `onclick` quando ela está dentro de `$(document).ready`? No exemplo ele não funciona, nem se eu fizer em um arquivo `.js` mesmo '-'

Aqui segue o código no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aandrade/q5yuqnq6/6/)

Comment: O proposito de usar jquery é justamente eliminar aquele monte de javascript em linha no html, e ter a flexibilidade dos seletores como no CSS, prefira fazer tudo com jquery como neste [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/q5yuqnq6/19/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quando vc coloca o $(document).ready não funciona porque as funções javascript devem ficar fora dele.

fiz umas alterações no javascript, dá uma olhada e vê se entendeu.
Eu removi a função insertDado() por:

```
$('#listaServicos li a').click(function() {
    var dado = $(this).parent().find('p').text();
    $('#dado').val(dado);
    alert(dado);
});
```

codigo http://jsfiddle.net/q5yuqnq6/8/

Comment: Ficou super simples e melhor rsrs. Agora entendi o motivo do $document.ready não funcionar. Valeu, cara. Vou dar uma estudada sobre o uso do parent(), ainda não tinha visto nada com ele ^^

Comment: o parent() nada mais faz do que fazer referencia para o pai do elemento em questão, por exemplo, se vc usar o parente em uma li ele ira fazer referencia ao pai ul.

Comment: +1 só que eu iria um pouco além: da mesma forma que você retirou o `insertDado` do `onclick` (usando um seletor jQuery em vez disso), eu faria o mesmo com o `filtraServico`. Assim, não "poluímos o namespace" adicionando novas funções globais sem necessidade. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5yuqnq6/16/)

Answer (score 4):

Você está pegando todos os conteúdos porque quando você coloca `$('.insert').text()` você pega o texto de todos os elementos com classe .insert.

Funciona se você fizer um evento do clique:

```
$(".insert").click(function(){
    var conteudo = $(this).text();
});
```

Dessa forma ele pega o texto do lugar onde você clicou.

Para fazer a função click é desse mesmo jeitinho, e funciona normal dentro de $(document).ready. A sintaxe é

```
$("seletor").click(function(){
  // o que acontece ao clicar
});
```

Como você já deve ter notado com o primeiro exemplo que eu dei, hehe. Se você vai usar isso dentro da função `insertDado()`, você tem de executar essa função depois de definir, apenas escrevendo `insertDado()` dentro do `$(document).ready`.

Espero que não tenha ficado muito confuso.

Comment: E sua explicação ficou bem clara, foi tranquilo pra entender ^^

Comment: Estou no celular mas parece certo; mas porque você comentou o document.ready? E você precisa executar essa função para funcionar. Escreva o nome dela dentro de document.ready.

Comment: Caso tenha visto o comentário de eu falando que não funcionou, esqueça. Ele funcionou sim rsrs. É que ele não tá abrindo no `onclick` e sim quando clica no elemento `li` rsrs.